# Error - unable to complete request when i click on save attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting the error on Manage Attribute Set.When i click on Save attribute set i get an pop-up which is unable to complete request.I tried clearing the cache and still facing the issue.
below link /admin/catalog_product_set/edit

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try delete all files and folders in var/cache/ and var/session/.

Run below commands at Magento root folder:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/session/*
```

It works for my case.